# How to write AppleScript for clicking an OK button on a custom dialog?

Tags: applescript, ical

I have done a script to quit program:

```
tell application "Live"
    quit
end tell
```

…but I get this prompt to click the OK button:

[image: Ableton Live]

I am running my Mac for schedule shutdown as it is running for an exhibition with unman on/off.

Could someone help me write an AppleScript to click this button?

Answer (score 1):

You might simulate pressing command-Q and return instead:

```
delay 0.5 -- time to release modifier keys if for example the script is run with command-R
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmost of process "Live" to true
    keystroke "q" using command down
    keystroke return
end tell
```

Or use `ignoring application responses` so the `quit` command doesn't block the script:

```
delay 0.5
ignoring application responses
    quit application "Live"
end ignoring
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
```